# Android using Drawables in an Enum

Tags: android, enums, drawable

I have a project that I have to design an array of coins and work with it. My GUI looks like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9evmz.png

I want to be able to load the appropriate image from the coinArray for each coin. basically i want to be able to say *coinView.setBackgroundResource(coinArray[x].image)*  i assume i need to somehow use a drawable object and i was hoping its possible to include it in my enum class. the enum class looks like

```
public enum Currency {
    Penny(1), Nickel(5), Dime(10), Quarter(25);
    private int value;
    private Currency(int value) {
            this.value = value;

    }

}
```

Each coin in the array has a currency value so i can compute them. I'd like to add a drawable or some other object that will allow me to refernce the correct image for each coin.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public enum Currency {
    Penny(1,R.drawable.xxx), Nickel(5,R.drawable.yyy),...;
    private int value;
    private int image
    private Currency(int value,int drawableId) {
            this.value = value;
            this.image=drawableId;

    }
    public int getImage(){
       return image;
    }

}
```

There are many ways you can do this. This is one of them. to use it:

```
coinView.setImageResource(coinArray[x].getImage());
```

Comment: hmm.. one small thing, coinView.setBackgroundResource(coinArray[x].getImage()) throws an error  saying that setBackgroundResource cannot accept an int value

Comment: [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))